# How to sort by defined value in mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

In my project I'm using SpringBoot 1.4.0-M2 and MongoDb 3.0

I want to implement sorting.

I have collection of documents:

```
{
"name":"Tim",
"age":19
}
,{
"name":"Jim",
"age":20
}
,{
"name":"Will",
"age":21
}
,{
"name":"Ed",
"age":22
}
```

I random number from 19 - 22, lets pretend that a number I have got is 21.
Now I want to order by "age" property using my the 21 value.

I want to have order like this 21,22,19,20 so Will,Ed,Tim,Jim

Do You know how to sort in this way?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to achieve this "wrapping sort" concept in a single query, but you could do it in two queries. The examples below load everything into memory, so you would just need to change things around a bit if you only wanted to operate on one at a time in the case of very large collections.

If you are using the native MongoDB Java driver 3.x:

```
int age = 21;
DBObject ageSort = new BasicDBObject("age", 1)
List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
mongoCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("age", new BasicDBObject("$gte", age)))
               .sort(ageSort)
               .forEach((Block<Document>) results::add);
mongoCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("age", new BasicDBObject("$lt", age)))
               .sort(ageSort)
               .forEach((Block<Document>) results::add);
```

If you are using Spring Data MongoDB:

```
int age = 21;
Sort ageSort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "age"))
List<Map> results = mongoTemplate.findAll(
    new Query(Criteria.where("age").gte(age)).with(ageSort),
    Map.class
);
results.addAll(mongoTemplate.findAll(
    new Query(Criteria.where("age").lt(age)).with(ageSort),
    Map.class
));
```

Comment: I have to do this in single querry, I think that I add aditional properties in my documents to archive this sorting effect, what do You think about it?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how you could achieve this in a single query.  Unless you know what the random number is ahead of time, I don't know what you could put in the documents ahead of time to assist with this. Can you share why this has to be a single query?